# Implementing a queue across multiple redis master servers

Tags: queue, redis

I am attempting to build a job queue using two redis master servers in two EC2 availability zones. All LPUSH operations are done in the application layer to both master machines in both AZs. Ideally I would be using [GitHub's resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque), but resque [does not seem to have any notion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590038/githubs-redis-and-resque-failure-behavior) of multiple masters in multiple AZs.

I need to ensure only one worker is working on a given job. Some workers will be in AZ 1A talking to the redis machine in 1A, and some will be in AZ 1B talking to the machine in 1B. I need to avoid the scenario where a worker in 1A and a worker in 1B both deque the same job from different redis masters and try to work on it simultaneously.

Does this worker pseudocode have any race conditions that I may have missed?

```
job_id = master1.BRPOPLPUSH "queue", "working"
m1lock = master1.SETNX "lock.#{job_id}"
m2lock = master2.SETNX "lock.#{job_id}"
completed = master1.ZSCORE "completed", job_id

if completed
  # must have been completed just now on other server, no-op
  master1.LREM "working", 0, job_id
  master1.del "lock.#{job_id}"
  master2.del "lock.#{job_id}"
elsif not m1lock or not m2lock
  # other server is working on it? We will put back at the end of our queue
  master1.LPUSH "queue", job_id
  master1.LREM "working", 0, job_id
  master1.del "lock.#{job_id}" if m1lock
  master2.del "lock.#{job_id}" if m2lock
else
  # have a lock, it's not complete, so do work
  do_work(job_id)

  now = Time.now.to_i
  master1.ZADD "completed", now, job_id
  master2.ZADD "completed", now, job_id

  master1.del "lock.#{job_id}"
  master2.del "lock.#{job_id}"

  master1.LREM "working", 0, job_id
  master2.LREM "queue", 0, job_id # not strictly necessary b/c of "completed"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to do in essence is master-master replication, whether it's a queue or anything else, redis doesn't support it, and your pseudo code has race conditions.
just doing:

```
m1lock = master1.SETNX "lock.#{job_id}"
m2lock = master2.SETNX "lock.#{job_id}"
```

means another worker can take the job while you are doing this, and two workers will work on it at once.
I don't think redis is ideal for your pattern, and I don't know any queue server that can work that way, but then again, I don't know many such servers, so I'm sure there is.

If you load balance your work so that only one master gets a job at once, it is possible, but then you have two queues in essence, not one.

Comment: SETNX returns a failure if it is unable to acquire the lock, so in theory they both would fail if they execute simultaneously and work would not be done, so I think I would be okay (I suppose in one case if there was only 1 job in the queue I could end up in a situation where I was failing to lock repeatedly, so I might want some kind of backoff period, but in the real world my queues will be variable length so I doubt I'd stay in that case for very long). I know redis doesn't support this, hence my need to do it at the application level, since EC2 machines & AZs can and do fail...

Comment: if either client will address the first master first, and not the nearest master - how does it really differ from chained replication (master - slave/master - slave)?

Comment: In my actual code the client does attempt to contact his nearest master (the one in his AZ), and if he cannot he will go to the master in the other AZ. (FWIW during the Amazon Cloudpocalypse of April 2011, I had to fully shut down master machines in one of my two AZs, hence this approach...)

Comment: It could work, but if the script dies, you'll be stuck with a zombie job. so I'd add expiration on the locks or something. you still have a possible race condition when putting a job back to the queue and then deleting the locks - it could result in another worker taking the job and thinking it's locked. just reverse the order maybe. but the 2 AZs thing can work, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious... if you're already in the AWS environment, why wouldn't you choose instead to use Amazon's SQS service?  I've worked with it in the past and realize it's a bit of a pain in the ass, but it's Amazon's most mature service and it's purpose built for this scenario.

Comment: Because of this blog post: https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque Quote: "We were a young site and heard stories on Amazon forums of multiple minute lag times between push and pop. That is, once you put something on a queue you wouldn't be able to get it back for what could be a while. That scared us so we moved." I'll also be doing so many queueing operations that I'm concerned it could get expensive. I'm basically attempting to queue all write ops to RDS because of its unpredictable write latency.

Comment: LMAO... good call.  Don't even get me STARTED on RDS latency.  I got burned bad by that one.  FYI, if RDS latency is what's ailing you, know that mysql running old school (aka on real hardware) kicks the shit out of RDS all day long.  When we ran headlong into RDS latency issues we pulled our mysql database off the cloud and moved back to the cloud only after switching our system to run off of cassandra and redis.

Comment: Our experience right now is that RDS latency is super-awesome (meaning very very low), except when it isn't. Actually after researching some more I've decided to move forward with the Amazon SQS solution and queue 100% of my writes to RDS through SQS. Even if it does take minutes to pull something out of the SQS queue, for our workload that is tolerable.